# "What" does oauth_signature sign?

Tags: digital-signature

In the section [6.1.1. Consumer Obtains a Request Token](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step1) of the OAuth Spec says that you  must send a request that contains the following paramter:

```
oauth_signature:
    The signature as defined in Signing Requests.
```

But how can you sign the request if the `oauth_signature` itself is part of it? I mean, "what" do you sign? All the fields except the `oauth_signature` or what?

For example, in the [The OAuth 1.0 Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) they provide the following example of obtaining the temporary credentials:

```
POST /initiate HTTP/1.1
Host: photos.example.net
Authorization: OAuth realm="Photos",
    oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="137131200",
    oauth_nonce="wIjqoS",
    oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fprinter.example.com%2Fready",
    oauth_signature="74KNZJeDHnMBp0EMJ9ZHt%2FXKycU%3D"
```

But how did they get the `oauth_signature` field? **What** was it that they *signed*?

Sorry, new to crypto - so dummy explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "signature base string" is being signed. It captures the "essence" of this particular request, so that that cannot be messed with. (Note that it does not include everything, especially not the request body).

In the example you linked to, read on for an example base string:

> For example, the HTTP request:

```
 POST /request?b5=%3D%253D&a3=a&c%40=&a2=r%20b HTTP/1.1
 Host: example.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Authorization: OAuth realm="Example",
                oauth_consumer_key="9djdj82h48djs9d2",
                oauth_token="kkk9d7dh3k39sjv7",
                oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
                oauth_timestamp="137131201",
                oauth_nonce="7d8f3e4a",
                oauth_signature="bYT5CMsGcbgUdFHObYMEfcx6bsw%3D"
```

> is represented by the following signature base string (line breaks
>      are for display purposes only):

```
 POST&http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Frequest&a2%3Dr%2520b%26a3%3D2%2520q
 %26a3%3Da%26b5%3D%253D%25253D%26c%2540%3D%26c2%3D%26oauth_consumer_
 key%3D9djdj82h48djs9d2%26oauth_nonce%3D7d8f3e4a%26oauth_signature_m
 ethod%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D137131201%26oauth_token%3Dkkk
 9d7dh3k39sjv7
```

Comment: Aah! I see, [Section 9](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process) provides a clear explanation of how to do it, stating in 9.1.1 that `The oauth_signature parameter MUST be excluded.`

Comment: Thank you for this detailed example.  It helped me catch which ampersands to escape, and which not to.